# no method 'adapter' in 'io' (node.js, heroku, RedisCloud, socket.io)

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, redis

Using RedisCloud on Heroku with node.js to allow (future) scaling to more than one dyno.

Got Redis working by following this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-from-node-js

For example the line below with the comment "Prints 'bar'" does write 'bar' to the console.

Then followed this to add socket.io-redis for scaling:
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-redis

The above should allow me to use something like the following:

```
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

The equivalent in my code below is:

```
io.adapter(ioredis (redisOptions));
```

However, I kept getting an error saying that io had no method 'adapter'.

Or if I checked first with an 'if' statement to see if io.adapter existed (as shown in code below), then the conditional code never executed.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  Why doesn't io.adapter exist?

in package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^0.12.1",
    "express": "^3.4.8",
    "socket.io": "^0.9.16",
    "socket.io-redis":"^0.1.4"
  }
```

also tried adding this to package.json

```
"socket.io-adapter": "^0.2.0"
```

in app.js (my node server code):

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
, redis = require('redis')
, ioredis = require('socket.io-redis')
, url = require('url')
, redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
```

And later in app.js :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var pub1 = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {return_buffers: true});
    var sub1 = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {return_buffers: true});
    pub1.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);
    sub1.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);

    var redisOptions = {
      pubClient: pub1,
      subClient: sub1,
      host: redisURL.hostname,
      port: redisURL.port
    };
    pub1.set('foo', 'bar');
    sub1.get('foo', function (err, reply) {
    console.log("redis test : "+reply.toString()); 
    // Prints 'bar'
      });
    if (io.adapter) {
        // Never reached
        io.adapter(ioredis (redisOptions));
        console.log ("mylog: io.adapter found");    
    }
    console.log ("mylog server connection event fired");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io-redis is meant to be used with socket.io 1.x.

The 0.9.x version doesn't have the adapter.

Comment: Changed to the following in package.json:  "socket.io": "^1.0.0"  and the adapter is there!  Thanks you Barış !